# Reading email using ruby-mail is not returning the mail body in text format

Tags: ruby, email, rubygems, mail-gem

Im using ruby-mail to read a email.

Everything im getting in proper readable format, except mail body.

Mail body appears as some other encoding format.

My code is :

```
Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "some.email.com",
              :port       => 995,
              :user_name  => 'domain/username',
              :password   => 'pwd',
              :enable_ssl => true
end


puts "From"
puts mail.from
puts "Sender:"
puts mail.sender
puts "To:"
puts mail.to              
puts "CC:"
puts mail.cc              
puts "Subject:"
puts mail.subject         
puts "Date:"
puts mail.date.to_s       
puts "MessageID:"
puts mail.message_id      
puts "Body:"
#puts mail.body
```

Output is :

From
legalholdnotification123@emc.com

Sender:

To:
bhavesh.sharma@emc.com

CC:

Subject:
case4: Legal Hold Notification

Date:
2012-04-24T14:46:25-04:00

MessageID:
3298720.1335293185423.JavaMail.root@vm-bhaveshok7

Body:

Date: Sat, 05 May 2012 09:45:08 -0700
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <4fa559147a120_138455aab4289ac@USITHEBBASL2C.mail>
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SO i cannot read the mail body.

What needs to be done so that i can read the mail,  i need to extract the text from the body and have to use the link that are present inside the mail body.

Bhavesh

Comment: The body is in base64. You need to [decode it](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-decode64).

Comment: One way to do it is to save mail.encoded to a file with an .eml extension, which can be opened in some email applications (e.g. Outlook). This way you can view the whole email, including attachments.

Answer (score 6):

The mail gem doesn't automatically decode the body. You can use:

```
mail.message.body.decoded
```

to get the decoded message body.
In addition you might find that you want to access the plain of the HTML parts of a message. In order to do this you could use something like the following:

```
plain_part = message.text_part ? message.text_part.body.decoded : nil
html_part = message.html_part ? message.html_part.body.decoded : nil
```

You could then use the `message.body.decoded` as a fallback in case these parts don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem and just use email body format with mail.parts[1].body.decoded

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
[...]

ids = imap.search(['UNSEEN'])

ids.each do |msg_id|
  raw_msg = imap.fetch(msg_id,'RFC822').first.attr['RFC822']
  msg = Mail.read_from_string raw_msg
  msg_body_content = msg.multipart?? msg.text_part.body.decoded : message.html_part.body.decoded
end
```